# Rails API active model serializer root node not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I have a *rails 4.2.5* API app. For some reason, the JSON root node is not included in the response and I don't understand why.

```
curl  http://localhost:3000/api/v1/category/science
```

returns

```
{"title":"science","sub_categories":34}%
```

instead of

```
{"category": {"title":"science","sub_categories":34}%}
```

The code:

*controller*

```
class Api::V1::CategoryController < ApplicationController
  def show
    category = params[:category] || "sports"
    @category = Category.where(cat_title: category.capitalize).first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @category, serializer: CategorySerializer, root: "category" }
    end
  end
end
```

serializer

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :sub_categories

  def title
    URI::encode(object.cat_title.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8", replace: nil).downcase.tr(" ", "_"))
  end

  def sub_categories
    object.cat_subcats
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

have a look into your initializers, this should be commented out in `wrap_paramters.rb`:

```
# To enable root element in JSON for ActiveRecord objects.
# ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
#   self.include_root_in_json = true
# end
```

Comment: I also had to add this `ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json`

Comment: unfortunately, both solutions are not working for me with `Rails 4.2.10` and `gem 'active_model_serializers', git: 'https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers.git', branch: '0-10-stable'` any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

*Rails 5.0.0.1*

Using `ActiveMovelSerializers (0.10.2)` you just need to add an initializer:

**app/config/initializers/json_api.rb**

```
require 'active_model_serializers/register_jsonapi_renderer'

ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

Comment: It would be useful for others if you added the answer for Rails 4.2.5.
Do not mark mine as the answer since I just added it for Rails 5.0.0.1 for future reference. Maybe add what you did or if phoet's answer is correct, marks his as the answer, thanks.

Comment: yeah, can you please provide the solution for 4.x rails? I'd be appreciate